# NonlinearModelFit produces a very bad fit

Tags: fitting

I would like to get a good a fit for the following data:

```
data = 
  {{0.14, 0.02}, {0.66, 0.02}, {0.91, 0.02}, {1.17, 0.02}, {1.43,
     0.02}, {1.69, 0.02}, {1.95, 0.02}, {2.21, 0.02}, {2.47, 
    0.02}, {2.72, 0.02}, {2.98, 0.02}, {3.24, 0.02}, {3.76, 
    0.03}, {4.02, 0.04}, {4.28, 0.04}, {4.53, 0.06}, {4.79, 
    0.07}, {5.05, 0.09}, {5.31, 0.12}, {5.57, 0.17}, {5.83, 
    0.24}, {6.09, 0.39}, {6.34, 0.65}, {6.60, 1.22}, {6.86, 
    2.50}, {7.12, 4.12}, {7.38, 3.60}, {7.64, 2.21}, {7.90, 
    1.38}, {8.16, 0.97}, {8.41, 0.75}, {8.67, 0.59}, {8.93, 
    0.48}, {9.19, 0.43}, {9.45, 0.39}, {9.97, 0.34}, {10.22, 
    0.33}, {10.48, 0.33}, {11.00, 0.33}, {11.26, 0.34}, {11.52, 
    0.35}, {12.03, 0.38}, {12.55, 0.43}, {13.07, 0.48}, {13.33, 
    0.51}, {13.59, 0.55}, {14.10, 0.63}, {14.36, 0.66}, {14.88, 
    0.74}, {15.14, 0.77}, {15.40, 0.80}, {15.91, 0.86}, {16.17, 
    0.89}, {16.43, 0.91}, {16.95, 0.93}, {17.21, 0.95}, {17.47, 
    0.96}, {17.98, 0.97}, {18.24, 0.98}, {18.50, 0.98}, {19.02, 
    1.00}, {19.28, 1.00}, {19.53, 1.00}};
```

My function is

```
1/(1 - 1.04 E^(-k^2/(2 a)) (-b + c k^2 - d k^4))
```

I used this code but got a very bad answer

```
nlm = 
  NonlinearModelFit[
    data, 1/(1 - 1.04 (Exp[-k^2/(2 a)]*(-b + c*k^2 - d*k^4))), {a, b, c, d}, k]
```

As you see from the screen capture below, I'm getting a very bad fit.

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm["Function"][x], {x, 0, 20}]]
```

[image]

Here are estimates for the initial values of the parameters.

```
{{a, 13.99}, {b, 96.56}, {c, 3.745}, {d, 0.03458}}
```

I want to get the value of the function's parameters without using the initial value estimates because I do not always have them.

Comment: Please provide more explanations of what you want to do. You want to find a good fit, any fit, or you want to find a fit using functions of a particular form?

Comment: Is there some reason why you think that equation with the right coefficients fits the data?  Has this form of the equation been used before?  Any idea what the coefficients might be?  Your usage of `NonlinearModelFit` has 1.0 for the starting values of all of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for answering . i want to find a fit using functions of a particular form . In fact, I want to find the value of the constants of my equation.     
 
I have introduced the function I have described above@Jim Baldwin

Comment: `{a, b, c, d}` is equivalent to `{{a,1}, {b,1}, {c,1}, {d,1}}` where those values of `1` are the starting values for the iterative fitting procedure.  If the actual values are far away from that or vary wildly in magnitude, then the procedure might not either converge or end up with the appropriate estimates.  If you know the approximate values, you should use those as the starting values.

Comment: Thank you for answering .Yes i'm sure Because this equation has already been drawn.I have constants values, but I want them without using them fitting this function . 
 
sorry what mean this : <Your usage of NonlinearModelFit has 1.0 for the starting values of all of the parameters> @ Anton Antonov

Comment: {{a, 13.99}, {b, 96.56}, {c, 3.745}, {d, 0.03458}}  .But what should I do when I do not have the initial values?..@Jim Baldwin

Comment: What can you do?  Guess. Pray. Use `Manipulate` to try a variety of values.  Look for features of the data that result in good guesses for the parameters.  For example if there is a peak and there's a term that looks like `(x-a)^2`, then maybe setting the initial value of `a` to the `x` associated with the peak (or trough) might work.  Also, have you plotted the equation with those values?  Looks like a pretty bad fit.  (Should `{a, 13.99}` be `{a, 18.99}` ?

Comment: {{a, 13.99}, {b, 96.56}, {c, 3.745}, {d, 0.03458}} .But what should I do when I do not have the initial values?@JimBaldwin

Comment: Not possible without initial values? With no plans .It gets so hard@JimBaldwin

Comment: @nasrin. Wait until 2030 and ask for Google artificial intelligence...

Comment: Thank you for your excellent Guide @Mariusz Iwaniuk

Comment: Maybe this helps, see on this book https://www.elsevier.com/books/mathematica-navigator/ruskeepaa/978-0-12-374164-6 `page 820-822 Example 3.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness@MariuszIwaniu@Mariusz Iwaniuk@Jim Baldwin

Comment: Is it possible for me to send a photo of that example? my mail is : nasrin.maghaami@yahoo.com @MariuszIwaniu@Mariusz Iwaniuk

Comment: You need to find out a good way to guess initial parameters. It can be from the theory behind whatever produced those points. Otherwise, garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to give `NonlinearModelFit` as much knowledge as you have. For example if you know that parameters should be positive put it in *cons* argument.

```
fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {
    1/(1 - 1.04 (Exp[-k^2/(2 a)]*(-b + c*k^2 - d*k^4))), 
    0 < a && 0 < b && 0 < c && 0 < d
}, {a, b, c, d}, k];
fm@"BestFitParameters"
Show[Plot[fm[k], {k, 0, 20}], ListPlot@data]
```

[image: Plot of fitted function]

Comment: Excellent point about using all the knowledge you have.  Also, because the parameterization of the model has the parameters with somewhat different scales (i.e. estimates ranging from 0.036 to 101), if one knew roughly what scaling factors to use, then the constraints aren't needed:  `fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 1/(1 - 1.04 (Exp[-k^2/(2 a 10)]*(-100 b +  c*k^2 - (d/100)*k^4))), {a, b, c, d}, k]`.

Comment: ...which again means that the experimenter doing the fitting really must have a sensible choice of scale/units before even attempting a fit.

Comment: woooooooooooow. it's very good.thank you so much.@jkuczm

Comment: I really appreciate all of you and I thank you for sharing your thoughts and knowledge. God knows your knowledge more and more and makes you successful.@Jim Baldwin@jkuczm@Anton Antonov@Mariusz Iwaniuk@J. M

Comment: I hope you will be successful and lucky, and you will be more and more knowledgeable day by day.@Anton Antonov@Jim Baldwin@jkuczm

Comment: Why can not I complete the chart?Even with the code" PlotRange -> All" Again, the graph with the shown line remains half-finished   @jkuczm

Comment: @nasrin Use `Show[Plot[fm[k], {k, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot@data]`.

Comment: @jkuczm .Thank you for your kindness. And to share your knowledge

Answer (score 2):

*(Extended comment, not an answer.)*

I think some of the assumptions you have about the fitting function form have to be re-examined.

Here is a better fit (I would say) obtained by extending the original form with a parameter and taking the absolute value.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  Abs[1/(1 - z (Exp[-k^2/(2 a)]*(-b + c*k^2 - d*k^4)))], {a, b, c, d, 
   z}, k]

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[nlm["Function"][k], {k, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Here is a plot of the relative errors:

```
diffs = Map[{#[[1]], 
     Abs[#[[2]] - nlm["Function"][#[[1]]]]/Abs[#[[2]]]} &, data];
ListPlot[diffs, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very good. The fit is better. Thank you, but it still has a lot of difference What for that...@Anton Antonov

Comment: I don't think that adding in `z` helps.  Only three of `b`, `c`, `d`, and `z` can be estimated because when you multiply through by `z` one sees that what remains are multiples of `b*z`, `c*z`, and `d*z`.  So one can estimate the 3 products but not the 4 separate parameters.

Comment: Seeing Jim Baldwin's comment and the up-votes to it, I would like to point out that without the `z` we do not get a good fit. This is seen both in [this image](http://i.imgur.com/O2VHGEN.png) and OP's question. (And I wonder why such blatant ignoring of evidence...)